# Random article API call is returning User talk pages?

Tags: javascript, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

I'm trying to pull a random article from the WikiMedia API, but my code seems to only grab User talk pages...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.getJSON("http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=random&prop=extracts&exchars=500&format=json&callback=?", function (data) {
    console.log(data.query.pages);
  });
});
```

I read that "generator=random" pulls a random article, but that does not seem to be the case. How do I get it working as intended?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to get only pages in namespace 0, you need to specify the `rnnamespace` parameter. And since you're using `list=random` as a generator, it's spelled as `grnnamespace`:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=random&grnnamespace=0&prop=extracts&exchars=500&format=json

Comment: That's quite ingenious... I did not find that in the MediaWiki API reference. I've removed my comment that it was impossible and linked your answer.

Comment: Awesome! The API returned some warning about namespace but I didn't think that was the problem. Accepting this answer instead for future readers.

Comment: What parameters should be used to get the extracts of more than one page via this query?

Comment: @VishnuKs `grnlimit=max&exlimit=max&exintro`

Answer (score 1):

<del>The API does not allow you to directly get random pages; the random generator currently gets random pages from *any* namespace.</del> **EDIT:** I stand corrected; apparently you can by passing in a `grnamespace` parameter, as [svick mentions in their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20163407/558592). I'll leave my original answer below though.

How about making two API calls?

First, make a call to grab a list of random pages:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=random&rnnamespace=0&rnlimit=5&format=json
```

Adjust the `rnlimit` parameter based on how many pages you want.

To get the wiki-source, use the following (replacing TITLE1, TITLE2, etc. with your actual titles):

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=TITLE1|TITLE2&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=json
```

For an HTML copy of the pages, use the following (replacing TITLE with your actual title, and calling the API repeatedly):

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&page=TITLE&prop=text&format=json
```

Of course, it might just be easier to call [Special:Random](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random) directly, and screen-scrape:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random
```

Comment: “The API does not allow you to directly get random pages” That's wrong, see my answer.